# Pivot and Insert

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have two tables. One is like this

[image]

The other is like this

[image]

How can I use one MySQL query to insert all users subject, total scores of those terms to table two. I have manage to insert only first term but the rest I couldn't.

For table one, here is the structure

```
CREATE TABLE  result (
  sno int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  total double DEFAULT NULL,
  class varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  session varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  term enum('First','Second','Third') DEFAULT NULL,
  subject varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  sname varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  subject_position varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  admission_no varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sno),
  KEY FK_course_reg_student_id (admission_no),
  KEY FK_course_reg_courseCode (subject)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23700 DEFAULT ;
```

The second table is

```
  p_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  session varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  adm varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  class varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  subject varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  first varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  second varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  third varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  total varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  grade varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (p_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2521 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me how to get the session, class, and grade columns for the second table from your first table screenshot. Excluding those columns, you can try this

```
with t1 as (
select distinct a.admission_no,
   a.subject,
   ifnull((select b.total from TableA b where b.admission_no = a.admission_no and a.subject = b.subject and b.term = 'First'),0) as first,
   ifnull((select b.total from TableA b where b.admission_no = a.admission_no and a.subject = b.subject and b.term = 'Second'),0) as second,
   ifnull((select b.total from TableA b where b.admission_no = a.admission_no and a.subject = b.subject and b.term = 'Third'),0) as third
from TableA a
where 1=1
)

insert into TableB (adm, subject, first, second, third, total)

select t1.admission_no,
   t1.subject,
   t1.first,
   t1.second,
   t1.third,
   (t1.first + t1.second + t1.third) as total
from t1
where 1=1
```

This insert assumes the primary key on TableA is (admission_no,subject, term). Depending on how large the tables are, this may not be the best solution from a performance perspective because generally I think you would want to avoid subqueries in the select, maybe a pivot option if available in MySql?

Could you post the full table definitions including the primary keys in order to get full insert with all the columns.